# Erklärung der Beugung des Wortes „Erlenkönig“ im Gedicht Goethes

Tags: grammatical-case

Das zu verstehende Wort ist „Erlkönig“, das im Nominativ vorliegt (falls ich es richtig verstehe). Woher kommt das Wort *Erlenkönig*? Was für eine Beugung ist das? Das ist vermutlich altes Deutsch. Aber könnte jemand dessen Beugung erklären?

> Mein Sohn, was birgst du so bang dein Gesicht?
>   Siehst Vater, du den Erlkönig nicht!
>   Den *Erlenkönig* mit Kron' und Schweif?
>   Mein Sohn, es ist ein Nebelstreif.

Ballade **[Erlkönig](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlk%C3%B6nig_%28Ballade%29)** von J.W. von Goethe.

Comment: Interessant finde ich, dass in zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Zeilen erst *Erlkönig* und anschließend *Erlenkönig* verwendet wird. Man könnte meinen, es ist poetischer Natur.

Comment: LOL einem Gedicht poetische Natur zu attestieren ist schon clever. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich schätze, das liegt einfach am Versmaß und hat gar nichts mit Grammatik zu tun:

Goethe benötigte eine zusätzliche Silbe und hat darum in der dritten Zeile das "-en" eingefügt. Konkret war hier eine unbetonte Silbe nötig, weil es sonst zu folgendem unschönen Rhythmus gekommen wäre:

> *Den Érl/köníg... (also grauenhafte Betonung der zweiten Silbe von "König")

Mit der zusätzlichen Silbe verschiebt sich die Betonung an die richtige Stelle:

> Den Ér/len K´ö/nig... (Betonung der ersten Silbe von "König")

(Darum auch das auf eine Silbe verkürzte "Kron" - nur so passt alles ins Versmaß)

---

Das ist in der Dichtung legitim, sollte im normalen Sprachgebrauch aber nicht gemacht werden... :)

Gibt es auch im Englischen recht häufig (oft seht dann auf der Endsilbe "-ed" ein Akzent):

> Our **bruis/ed** arms/ hung up/ for mon/uments, [Richard III, 1.1.6]

Oder auch das Gegenteil, wenn eine Silbe verschluckt wird:

> He **ne’er**/ lift up/ his hand/ but con/quered.
>   [1 Henry VI, 1.1.16]

Beide Beispiele von [hier](http://www.shakespeare-usa.com/Scansion.htm), Hervorhebung von mir.

---

Habe gerade [hier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35347/what-does-the-grave-accent-mark-on-words-mean) noch einen Eintrag dazu gefunden.

Comment: Das gibt es nicht nur in der Poesie, sondern auch in ganz normalem Gebrauchstexten. Beispielsweise hat das Gelenk, dass den Unterarm mit dem Oberarm verbindet, die beiden gleichberechtigten Namen "Ellbogen" und "Ellenbogen".

Comment: Prima facie war Ihre Antwort die beste. Ich finde Ihre Erklärung schön! Aber wenn die für die befragte Änderung verantwortlich ist, warum wird die letzte Silabe in "Krone" zu "Kron'" verschluckt? Goethe fügt eine Silabe in "Erl*en*könig" und dann löscht andere Silabe in "Kron'", das in der selben Zeile vorliegt.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Zu manch' Zeit ist es des Rhytmus wegens wert, die Silbe manch'orts zu entwenden und sie zu schieben an and'rer Stell'.

Comment: @Em1: *cringe*...

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Vielen Dank! :)
Was Em1 meint, ist, dass es hier um betonte und unbetonte Silben geht - ich füge in die Antwort noch eine Erklärung ein...

Answer (score 12):

### König der Elfen

Es gibt eine alte dänische Geschichte um den König der Elfen, also den Elfenkönig. Das dänische Wort für „Elfenkönig“ ist „Ellerkonge“, denn das dänische Wort für „Elfe“ ist „Eller“. Johann Gottfried Herder hat diese dänische Ballade ins Deutsche übersetzt und dabei einen Übersetzungsfehler gemacht. Er übersetzte das dänische Wort „Eller“, das ja eigentlich „Elfe“ (ein mythisches Wesen) heißt, als „Erle“ (eine Baumart).

Goethe kannte die deutsche Übersetzung der Ballade vom Erlkönig und schrieb sie um, um sie an den Anfang des Singspiels „Die Fischerin“ zu setzen, wo die Fischerin ebendiese Ballade singt.

Dass der König einmal „Erlkönig“ und dann wieder „Erlenkönig“ genannt wird, hat ebenso wenig zu bedeuten, wie dass manche Menschen „Ellbogen“ oder „Ellenbogen“ zum Gelenk zwischen Unter- und Oberarm sagen. Goethe wählte jeweils die Version, die besser ins Versmaß passte.

**Nachtrag**
Ein anderes dänisches Wort für „König“ ist „rich“. Der Elfenkönig wird also nicht nur Ellerkonge, sondern auch Ellerich genannt. Daraus entstanden dann Elberich und Alberich. Ein Zwerg mit dem Namen Alberich begegnet uns ja auch im Nibelungenlied.
Die Silbe „Alb“ wiederum findet man auch im Wort „Albtraum“, und die Alben sind auch nichts anderes als eine Variation der Elfen.

Der Elfenkönig selbst geht auf einen alten jüdischen Mythos zurück, dort war er aber noch – wie alle Elfen – eine Frau, die auch als „die weiße Frau“, eine todbringende Gestalt, in der Mythologie zu finden ist.

Comment: Sehr interessant. Hättest Du vielleicht eine Quellenabgabe für den jüdischen Mythos auf den der Elfenkönig zurückgeht?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Eine einzelne Quelle kann ich dir leider nicht bieten, aber die Elfenkönigin geht auf Lilith (Adams erste Frau; Eva war Adams zweite Frau) bzw. die griechische Göttin Alphito zurück. Lilith ist die Frau, die Gott zugleich mit Adam aus Lehm gemacht hat, die aber nicht unter Adam liegen wollte. Sie steht nicht in der Bibel, wohl aber im jüdischen Talmud. Sie dürfte auf die Sumerer zurückgehen.

Comment: Fortsetzung: Alphito ist auch sehr alt. Ihre Spuren reichen in die Zeit vor den allgemein bekannten griechischen Göttern zurück. Sie ist die Göttin der Gerste, kann Lepra verursachen und sich ein eine Sau verwandeln, die Leichen frisst. Auf sie geht auch der in Bibel erwähnte Mythos zurück, Gertenbrei würde vor Lepra schützen. (Alphito selbst wird in der Bibel aber namentlich nicht erwähnt)

Comment: Danke für diese zusätliche Erklärung, Hubert.

Answer (score 3):

Es handelt sich hier um eine poetische [Komposition](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komposition_%28Grammatik%29) aus [Erle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlen_%28Botanik%29) (*alder*) und König (*king*). Üblich ist dabei, dass der Kopf (hier *König*) die Grammatik der Komposition bestimmt (hier *Nominativ* und in der zweiten Zeile *Akkusativ*), während die Beugung des Kerns durch ihren Bezug zum Kopf bestimmt wird. In diesem Fall steht hier ein **Genitiv**:

> Der/den König der Erlen - Erlenkönig

Zur Bildung von Komposita können an der [Fuge](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) auch Vokale ausgelassen werden, um den Redefluss zu erleichtern, oder um hier ein poetisches [Versmaß](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/5423/23) zu erzielen.

Comment: Ah - so hatte ich die Frage gar nicht verstanden... +1!