# What's the meaning of 'erl'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, noun

"[Erlkönig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Erlk%C3%B6nig)" (also called "Der Erlkönig") is a poem by Johann Wolfgang von Goethe.

By wiki I know that the word `könig` means 'king', but what's the meaning of `erl`? Is it devil, elf, or genie?

Comment: wrong translation from danish  ellerkonge = Elfenkönig; http://board.battleknight.de/board119-archive/board128-archiv-f%C3%BCr-battleknight-im-schatten-des-rittertums/board217-archiv-fun-spam/12222-der-erlk%C3%B6nig-der-wahre-hintergrund/

Comment: @bummi Honestly, I'm not familiar with German, what's the major content in that post?

Comment: same with my english ;-( The substance of the ballad comes from the danish, there is the Erlkönig Ellerkonge, so elf king.

Comment: As far as I see the this answer to [Erklärung der Beugung des Wortes „Erlenkönig“ im Gedicht Goethes](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/5425/1224) does also answer your question.

Comment: @Em1,@bummi, I see, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ballad Erlkönig is originally Danish and named there "Ellerkonge"... meaning elf-king. Eller was falsely translated with "Erle" which is a German tree. So the short form of "Erle" is "Erl".

Hope that could answer it :)